# Send me email everytime a certain file is accessed from my apache server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, apache-http-server, shell-script

I want to have my server send me an email every time someone accesses a PDF file on my webserver.

Perhaps:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache.log | grep pdf > ??something??
```

How would I generate a new email message each time this tail/grep outputs something?
How could I have that running as a background script?

Answer (score 2):

You may achieve such a thing by playing with the [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) and [inotifywatch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch) commands, from the inotify-tools package.

Example with *inotifywait*:

```
inotifywait -m -e access -e open -e modify /var/www/html/index.html
```

Comment: Thanks.  For now I got the following sh script working.  It fits in my current experience level.  I may try inotifywait later.`#!/bin/bash
FILE=/var/log/apache2/access.log
TERM="pdf"

while read line; do
        echo $line | grep $TERM > /dev/null && echo $line | mail -s "new $TERM access" something@gmail.com
done < <(tail -1f $FILE)`